# Validation design: form or view?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I've made a "edit profile" form where you can to a very classical thing: change your password.

Thus I have 3 fields: old password, new password and retype new password.

The problem is about design.
I first check that everything typed is ok **in the form `clean` method**:

```
def clean(self):
    old = self.cleaned_data.get('old_password')
    new1 = self.cleaned_data.get('new_password1')
    new2 = self.cleaned_data.get('new_password2')
    if old:
        if not new1:
            raise ValidationError(_(u'New password missing'))
        if not new2:
            raise ValidationError(_(u'New password missing'))
        if new1 != new2:
            raise ValidationError(_(u"The new password "
                                    u"is not the same twice"))
    return super(ProfileForm, self).clean()
```

From my form, unless I hack, I cant access to the user currently logged in.
My question is about design: is it better to hack in the form code, and change the password there so in the **form** *`is_valid()`*, or is it better to do it in the **view** *`form_valid()`* method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django actually has a built-in form for changing a user's password which you can reference. See `SetPasswordForm` and `PasswordChangeForm`on https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/forms.py.

Don't change the password in the `is_valid()` method, it is used for validation only. You can override your form's `__init__` to take a user, and the `save` method to change the password.

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):

    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.user =  user

    def save(self, commit=True):
        password = self.cleaned_data["new_password1"]
        self.user.set_password(password)
        if commit:
            self.user.save()
        return self.user
```

The password changing operation should be done in the form in a separate method. Here's an example of the view code you would need:

```
class MyView(TemplateView):

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = MyForm(user=request.user, data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save() # password updated
            return redirect(<somehwere>)

        # the password change has failed form validation
        return self.render_to_response({})
```

To answer your question, it is better to change the password in the forms, as opposed to the view. It's a fairly common pattern in Django to perform data operations in forms (e.g. ModelForm.save()), and most of Django's own code also change model data in forms.

This separates the logic for changing model data from the view, and makes it much easier to unittest and reason about (e.g. you won't need to rely on a view for testing change password operation).

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, Django comes with a [view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.password_change) and [form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.forms.PasswordChangeForm) to change passwords], you should use them if possible.

If you really need to right your own view and form, I think it's ok to change the password in the views `form_valid()` method.

You could move the code that sets the new password to a method on the form, then call this method in the `form_valid` method. The disadvantage of this approach is that you will have to override the form's `__init__` method and the view's `get_form_kwargs` method to pass the user to the form, which makes it more complicated. The advantage is that you have encapsulated the functionality in the view.

Don't override the form's `is_valid()` method. The purpose of this method is to check whether or not the form is valid. You rarely need to override it.